# Test whole table React component cells with Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test individual rows and cells in a react component, the "return" of the component looks like:

```
return (
    <div className="app-body">
       <table className="grid">
           <tbody>
               {grid.map((row, rowIdx) => {
                   return <tr className="grid-row" key={rowIdx}>
                       {row.map((node, nodeIdx) => {
                           const { row, col } = node;
                               return <Node
                                   key={nodeIdx}
                                   row={row}
                                   col={col}></Node>
                            })}
                        </tr>
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
```

how can I test each cell in jest / Enzyme ?
I've been trying:

```
describe('test MyComponent', () => {
    const wrapper = render(<MyComponent />);
    const table = wrapper.find('table');
    const row = render(<tr />)
    const node = render(<Node />);

    it('table grid', () => {
        expect(table).toHaveLength(1);
        expect(row).toHaveLength(1);
        expect(node).toHaveLength(1);
    });
});
```

why it expecting only ONE node ? 
how can I collect all nodes in a table ?

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(wrapper.debug())` ? Which is the value of `grid` array passed to the component in your test?

Comment: It's returns that wrapper.debug is not a function. the grid is empty at first. it's an array of arrays of node objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is expecting 1 because there is only 1 `table` element to find (for the `expect(table)`). For the other two (`row` and `node`), you are just rendering single elements (completely independent of your `MyComponent`. If you are trying to count the number of tables, rows, and Nodes in `MyComponent`, try something like this:

```js
describe('test MyComponent', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);
    const table = wrapper.find('table');
    const row = table.find('tr')
    const node = table.find(Node)

    it('table grid', () => {
        expect(table).toHaveLength(1);
        expect(row).toHaveLength(whateverYouExpect);
        expect(node).toHaveLength(whateverYouExpect);
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you for helping! I'm trying but it returns both 0 for :  expect(row).toHaveLength(0);
expect(node).toHaveLength(0);

Comment: What if you use `mount` instead of `render`?